What exactly is a 山崩し in this context?


Perhaps because I'm not really knowledge of shogi but I'm confused about this sequence here. They are the shogi club and the character on the right wants to play while the one on the left is doing this thing with the pieces.
As far I understand "将棋崩し" is a game (as even explained in the panel)　where you stack pieces together and then move them to your territory without making a sound and fight by counting the numbers (assuming I got the explanation right)
He tells him (senpai) no way he's not gonna play 山崩ししをやるわけじゃないけど and if it's alright to I guess switch game (変更) which leads to the senpai commenting ほんとに山崩しやるのか "Are we really gonna play 山崩し?" and then they actually start play it.
Is my reading correct or am I missing something?

As you are including pictures of the book, I strongly believe that you need to specify the title, volume and the author of the book, and preferably the pages. It isn't about knowing the context: it's about proper attribution,

山崩し is a game that can be played with Shogi pieces[駒] (I'm familiar with a game called 将棋崩し, which I guess is the same). You correctly read the explanation of the rule. As you could imagine, less strategy and thinking is involved in 山崩し． Also, when preparing to play Shogi, one put pieces in their designated locations (just as in chess), while when preparing to play 山崩し, you make a pile of 駒.
Read this part as follows:

They are about to start playing (apparently shogi proper)
先輩 starts piling up 駒, instead of putting them in order. He seems distracted
The 後輩 points out they weren't going to play 山崩し， suggesting they can switch to it if he wants
先輩 apologises
後輩, knowing 先輩 is somewhat distracted, starts actually preparing for 山崩し (he's gathering 駒 randomly). He probably thinks that 先輩 is too inattentive to play a serious game, and starts 山崩し instead so that he can have him talk.
... During which 後輩 tells 先輩 that he does look distracted.
先輩 notices 後輩's movement and says that now we're really playing 山崩し
They start talking along with 山崩し．

If you need a visual explanation for 山崩し， it would look like this blog post, for example.

Oh I see.  The 変更 is about switching to actually play  山崩し. Thank you.
